# Is it ok to use irregular key signatures for neutral scales?

Tags: theory, notation, sheet-music, key-signatures, microtonality

[image: neutral scale]

So for 24-TET neutral scales is it correct to use irregular key signatures? or do I need to use a minor with accidentals or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you start operating outside of standard major/minor scales all bets are off key-signature-wise. Especially in microtonal music, you can "invent" your own key signature as is most convenient to express your ideas.